# Green pixels on local video playback

Tags: linux, video, vlc

I have installed VLC for linux without any errors all libraries are updated but the player (along with few others I tested like SMPlayer) shows green pixels moving at random across the screen. This doesn't happen with youtube videos. The only file formats I have tested are .avi and .mkv

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling the hardware acceleration first and see if that changes anything
https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_GPU_Decoding/